# PHP - Get the current working day number of the current month

Tags: php, calendar

I found this code in a answer here on stack overflow which counts working days of a month.

```
function get_weekdays($m,$y) {
    $lastday = date("t",mktime(0,0,0,$m,1,$y));
    $weekdays=0;
    for($d=29;$d<=$lastday;$d++) {
        $wd = date("w",mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d,$y));
        if($wd > 0 && $wd < 6) $weekdays++;
    }
    return $weekdays+20;
}
```

How can I get the current day number if I run this function for current month? ( I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I posted a new question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current day (as in, today is `29`) is just `date("d")`, day of the week is `date("w")` (3=Wednesday)

If you meant the working days for the current month, call that function with:

```
get_weekdays(date("m"), date("Y"));
```

To see what each format options means see [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)